# How to get string in nested parenthesis or square brackets by separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox which user write the formula as mathematical. For example user's input is `((a+b) + c)` so how can I get the string by separately in parenthesis

```
var txt = "((a+b) + c)";
var newTxt = txt.split('(');
for (var i = 1; i < newTxt.length; i++) {
    var value = newTxt[i].split(')')[0];
    console.log(value);
}
```

In this example I get only `a+b` but I'm trying to get strings separetely for example output like this

```
a+b

(a+b)+c
```

Comment: by code, which you'ven't posted in the question.

Comment: `eval(code)` is what you're looking for here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this value using Regular Expression, with this regex `^\((.+)\)$` you will get the value inside the outer parenthesis.

Here's the code you need:

```js
var reg = /^\((.+)\)$/;
var txt = "((a+b) + c)";
var value = txt.match(reg)[1];
alert(value);
```